Are all enveloping algebras $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ locally compact quantum groups?
Let us consider the enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ of some Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
Under what assumptions about $\mathfrak{g}$, does the enveloping algebra generate a locally compact quantum group in the sense of Kustermans and Vaes?
By that I mean, we generate the von Neumann algebra from the elements of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ understood as unbounded densely defined (differential) operators on $L^2(G)$.
Is it true that the generated von Neumann algebra is the group von Neumann algebra of the associated simply connected Lie group? Or does the algebra need to be (for example) semi-simple?
Edit: by 'the von Neumann algebra generated by an unbounded operator $T$', I mean:
$$ W^*(T) := \{ x \in B(H) \; | \; xT \subset Tx \text{ and } xT^* \subset T^*x \}' $$
so the usual generation ($T''$) but the 'first commutant' is the appropriate one for unbounded operators.
Thank you!

How are you proposing to generate a von Neumann algebra, which is by definition a set of bounded operators, from a set of unbounded operators on $L^2(G)$? I am not saying that it can't be done, but it might save people some head-scratching if you explained what you had in mind.

Thanks! I added an edit with the definition
